# 'CommentForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Tags: python, django

I tried this `if form.is_valid() and request.user.is_authenticated():`, it shows me that, bool obj is not callable. then i tried without parentheses then it shows error that, 'CommentForm' object has no attribute `cleaned_data`. please help me out, it would be appreciated.

```
def post_detail(request, slug=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if instance.publish > timezone.now().date() or instance.draft:
        if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
            raise Http404
    share_string = quote_plus(instance.content)

    initial_data = {
            "content_type": instance.get_content_type,
            "object_id": instance.id
    }
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial_data)
    if form.is_valid() and request.user.is_authenticated():
        c_type = form.cleaned_data.get("content_type")
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=c_type)
        obj_id = form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
        content_data = form.cleaned_data.get("content")
        parent_obj = None
        try:
            parent_id = int(request.POST.get("parent_id"))
        except:
            parent_id = None

        if parent_id:
            parent_qs = Comment.objects.filter(id=parent_id)
            if parent_qs.exists() and parent_qs.count() == 1:
                parent_obj = parent_qs.first()


        new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
                            user = request.user,
                            content_type= content_type,
                            object_id = obj_id,
                            content = content_data,
                            parent = parent_obj,
                        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(new_comment.content_object.get_absolute_url())


    comments = instance.comments
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "share_string": share_string,
        "comments": comments,
        "comment_form":form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just `is_authenticated` that doesn't need the parentheses.

```
if form.is_valid() and request.user.is_authenticated:
```